# Architecture for User-Registration (here: With using Facebook)

Tags: facebook, ember.js, ember-data, facebook-javascript-sdk, ember-cli

Im writing a user registration mechanism by hand so I dont want to use existing plugins or something.

Im wondering what the best way would be. I planning to do the following abstract steps:

1. Writing an component which is in charge to output a button which calls the facebook-api --> login in via facebook (Im getting token and user name/id)
2. In my route im using that Data to call the REST-Server-Backend of my app. I will pass the token as well as the username/id to the Server. (POST api.myapp.com/users)
3. The Server recieves the request and will validate via Facebook-API
   the user data and token on its own --> if valid: Add new user to
   database.
4. If the user wants to login now (after registration) he will do again
   step no.1 and than will ask the server if the user is existing. But
   how: Since ember suggest that the REST-Server is somekind of a
   CRUD-Server and using the store is for working for model data only, there
   is no possiblity to do a "*logic"-call* to the server like "***ask
   him if user with id is existing"***. Should I call "GET ../users/" and than check in my route if the sum of the returned records are smaller than 1?

So is that a common pattern?

Comment: I would image that this has been down voted because your question is a bit broad and could lead to bike shedding, also you can probably find the answers you're looking for with a bit of frugal googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a fairly simple OAuth workflow but obviously refer to the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4). As far as point 4 is concerned, I would suggest that yes, on login you make a request for the login route on your server (which should abstract the facebook OAuth call), and if the user is authenticated, then send down the `user` resource, otherwise redirect them to the login and send down some sort of `401` HTTP error.

As all your API calls should be authenticated too your user won't be able to access any protected API resources.

I would also suggest you look into an ember plugin like [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) which also [supports](http://ember-simple-auth.com/ember-simple-auth-oauth2-api-docs.html) OAuth.

You can find more information about OAuth2 workflows [here](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/workflow/).

Comment: Hi @Phil Hauser sounds clear so far. But Im wonderingabout the next steps. After auth with facebook, I want to "synchronized" that with my local server-database. But how can I communicate with my server in a not-only-for-model-data-way (like "hey server: is a user with name JohnDoe existing? Return true if yes") Ember-Data suggest that you only handle model data repecting the conventions.